# Rearranging a series to diverge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If the series $\sum a_n $ converges conditionally but not absolutely then it is well-known that we can rearrange the series to converge to any value or diverge to infinity.

I’d like to know if this method gives a rearrangement that diverges to $\infty$.

First one can prove that $(a_n)$ has infinitely many positive and negative terms and that the sum of the positive terms diverges to $\infty$ (the negatives to $-\infty$).

Define $A_-=\{n\in \mathbb N| a_n<0\}$ and $A_+=\{n\in \mathbb N| a_n\ge 0\}$.
Let $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that when $n$ is a power of $2$ $$f(n)=\min\{n\in A_-| n\neq f(i) \forall i<n \}$$
and $$f(n)=\min\{n\in A_+| n\neq f(i) \forall i<n \}$$ otherwise. (intuitively, at the $k$th place we put a negative term of $(a_n)$ whenever $k$ is a power of $2$ and a positive term otherwise). One can check that $f$ is a bijection. Now we have $$\sum_{k=1}^na_{f(k)} = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \log_2n\rfloor}a_{f(2^i)}+ \sum_{k\neq 2^i }a_{f(k)} $$

From this point I run out of notation ideas to express the second sum. The intuition behind this attempt is that the second sum has $n-\lfloor \log_2n\rfloor  -1$ terms which is significantly larger than the first sum and since the sum of the positive terms diverges to $\infty$ we might be able to make the whole sum as big as we want

Comment: Yes, sure, this method can give a rearrangement that diverges to $+\infty$. If you remember, in Riemann theorem proof we jump around a predetermined number to make series converging to it. To design the series that converge to $+\infty$ the idea is the same: the first step, jump after 1, go back before it, then jump after 2, go back before it, jump after 3 and so on... Hope, you got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to rephrase this. Let $(b_n)$ be the sequence of non-negative terms and $(c_n)$ be the sequence of negative terms, in the order they appear in $(a_n)$. The way I understand your question, you are asking whether
$$
c_1 + c_2 + b_1 + c_3 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + c_4 + b_5 + b_6 + \cdots
$$
(with $c$'s in all power-of-two spots) always diverges to $+\infty$.

This is not always true. You can't decide, ahead of time and independently of how large the terms are, which order you're going to include the negative and positive terms.

In particular, this doesn't even have to be an actual rearrangement. It's not very difficult to come up with a conditionally convergent sequence $(a_n)$ that is *already* in this order. For instance, take $c_n = -\frac 1n$, and make all the $b_k$ between $c_{n-1}$ and $c_n$ equal to $\dfrac{1}{n\cdot (2^{n-2} - 1)}$, giving us
$$
-1 -\frac12 + \frac13 - \frac13 + \frac1{12} + \frac1{12} + \frac1{12} -\frac14 + \frac1{35} + \frac1{35} + \cdots
$$
If we sum these terms in the above order, this would make each $c$ term exactly cancel out all the $b$ terms that came since the last $c$ term. All the partial sums from $n = 2^{k-1}$ to $n= 2^{k}$ (for $k\geq 2$) would slowly climb from $-\frac32$ to $-\frac32 + \frac1k$, and then immediately go down to $-\frac32$ again.

Comment: If you make a similar conditionally convergent sequence where the negative terms are significantly rarer than power-of-two positions (an immediate guess is that power-of-three positions will suffice) this rearrangement will actually cause the series to diverge to $-\infty$.